# Why is my Php not creating a file when it doesnt exist

Tags: php, csv

Im trying to have my php create a file with the correct index for the data and with the header at the top of the csv with the data entry with the index just below, currently I can have the data inputted into the csv when the header is already in the file and the file already exists. How can I make it so it creates the file automatically in the chosen directory.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // Collect the form data.
    $fileName = dirname(__DIR__ . '/..') . "ModuleData" . ".csv";
    $file = new SplFileObject($fileName, 'r');
    $file ->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);
    $index = $file -> key();
    $moduleCode = isset($_POST['module-code']) ? $_POST['module-code'] : '';
    $moduleName = isset($_POST['module-name']) ? $_POST['module-name'] : '';
    $lecturer = isset($_POST['lecturer']) ? $_POST['lecturer'] : '';
    $semYear = isset($_POST['SemYear']) ? $_POST['SemYear'] : '';

    // Check if module code is set.
    if ($moduleCode == '') {
        $errors[] = 'Module code required';
    }

    // Validate the module name.
    if ($moduleName == '') {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid module name';
    }

    // Validate the lecturer name.
    if ($lecturer == '') {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid lecturer name';
    }

    // Validate the semester year.
    if ($semYear == '') {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter a valid date';
    }

    // If no errors, carry on.
    if (!isset($errors)) {
        // The header row of the CSV.
        $header = "index,moduleCode,moduleName,lecturer,semYear\n";
        // The data row of the CSV.
        $data = "$index,$moduleCode,$moduleName,$lecturer,$semYear\n";

        // Create or append to the CSV file.
        $file = fopen($fileName, 'a+');
        if ($file) {
            // If the file exists, append the data.
            fwrite($file, $data);
            fclose($file);
            echo 'success';
        } else {
            // If the file doesn't exist, create it and add the header and data.
            $file = fopen($fileName, 'w');
            if ($file) {
                fwrite($file, $header . $data);
                fclose($file);
                echo 'success creating file';
            } else {
                echo 'failed to create file';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I've got currently.

Comment: are you sure that the base path permission is accepting writing files?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 3 problems:

1. > [**'a+'**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)   Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

   This flag will automatically create files that do not exist. Since `fopen` returned false, it means there is a problem with the path you passed.
2. > [**dirname()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) operates naively on the input string, and is not aware of the actual filesystem, or path components such as "..".

   Therefore the result of `dirname(__DIR__ . '/..')` is equivalent to `__DIR__`. If you want to fetch the parent directory of the current file, you should use:

   ```
   dirname(__DIR__)
   ```
3. > **dirname()**: Otherwise, the returned string is path with any trailing /component removed.

   Except for the root directory, the return result of `dirname` does not contain a trailing slash. So this `dirname(....) . "ModuleData"` is likely an incorrect path, and you need to add a separator:

   ```
   dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "ModuleData"
   ```

Comment: I have added the directory separator and the pointer at the end of the file and I now have it creating a file to the correct directory when empty but it does not input the header into the file on creation and I'd have to do it manually.